# tweepy.error.TweepError: This method does not perform pagination

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm learning how to make a Twitter bot.

I created a 'last_seen.txt' file to keep track of Tweets that the have already interacted with.

I'm using this code:

```
def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return
```

After that I declared this:

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended'), q).items(tweetNumber)
```

Now I get the error:

```
 raise TweepError('This method does not perform pagination')
tweepy.error.TweepError: This method does not perform pagination
```

For the last line.

Is there another way to declare that line?
I understand the code is not intrinsically incorrect, just not supported.

//Editing with full code //

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

FILE_NAME = 'last_seen.txt'

def read_last_seen(FILE_NAME):
    file_read = open(FILE_NAME, 'r')
    last_seen_id = int(file_read.read().strip())
    file_read.close()
    return last_seen_id

def store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, last_seen_id):
    file_write = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
    file_write.write(str(last_seen_id))
    file_write.close()
    return

tweetNumber = 20
q = "My search"

tweets = list(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, tweet_mode='extended').items(tweetNumber))


def crashBot():
    

    for tweet in reversed(tweets):
            
        try:                
            if q in tweet.full_text.lower():
                print(str(tweet.id) + '-' + tweet.full_text)
                api.update_status("@" + tweet.user.screen_name + " My Reply!", tweet.id)
                api.create_favorite(tweet.id)
                api.retweet(tweet.id)                    
                print("done!")
                store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)
                time.sleep(10)            
        except tweepy.tweepyError as e:
            print(e.reason)
            time.sleep(10)
            
while True:
    crashBot()    
    time.sleep(10)
```

Current errors:

```
raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 187, 'message': 'Status is a duplicate.'}]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crashBot.py", line 53, in <module>
    crashBot()
  File "crashBot.py", line 48, in crashBot
    except tweepy.tweepyError as e:
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'tweepyError'
```

or

```
 raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [`tweepy.Cursor`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor), you need to pass the `API` method without calling it and pass the arguments to the cursor as you would to the method.

Also, [`Cursor.items`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor.items) returns an iterator, not the actual Status objects. You'll probably want to cast it to a list or iterate through it.

For example:

```
tweets = list(tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q, tweet_mode='extended').items(tweetNumber))
```

I'm not sure how you're using `read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)`, but you'll want to pass it in the same way you would pass it to `API.search`. If it's the query itself, simply replace `q` with it.

Comment: Originally I was using: `tweets = api.search(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')` - but because I needed to add more things to the tweets variable I had to improvise, not sure how I can do this now. this code is supposed to add the tweet ID to a file text.

Comment: Again, if it's the query itself like this, you can simply replace `q` with it in the example.

Comment: I'm not trying to store the query, I'm trying to store the twitter ID into a text file. If I add `read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)` and replace the `q` nothing happens and the code doesn't run. If I don't insert `read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)` at all the code runs once and gives an error. I should be able to get the ID from `store_last_seen(FILE_NAME, tweet.id)` to know that I didn't interact with that tweet before. I'm not sure how to get this working. As I mentioned your suggestion works but only runs once, because it tries to run on the same tweet again. The `q` is the search the bot is performing.

Comment: here the current error `raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 139, 'message': 'You have already favorited this status.'}]`

Comment: `tweets = api.search(read_last_seen(FILE_NAME), tweet_mode='extended')` is passing `read_last_seen(FILE_NAME)` as the query, `q`. Again, to paginate using Cursor, you can simply pass the arguments to it as you would to the `API` method. It's not very clear what you're trying to do. You'll need to provide your actual code and error(s), along with your expected results, if you want more help beyond using Cursor.

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the code you've shown. It almost certainly involves different code and a different question involving that code. Without the actual code and full traceback, it'll be impossible to help you further.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I added the full code to the question with the current errors.

Comment: I have set this as answered as you have provided the fix for the original question. I have also found a way to fix my code. Just had to increase the `tweetNumber` and it worked... for some reason.